# How to extract values from arrays using upper and lower limits?

Tags: c#, arrays

Given two arrays, I need to extract values from arrayB based on where the range(actual values) falls in arrayA.

```
Index     0    1  2    3  4    5  6   7   8     9  10   11  12
-------------------------------------------------------------
ArrayA = {0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4,  4.5,  5, 5.5,  6}
ArrayB = {1, 0.2, 3,   4, 5,   6,5.5,  8,  9,11.1, 11,  12,  3}
```

Given the following ranges, I need to extract the following results

```
RangeToExtract*  IndexInArrayA  Expected Values To Extract
--------------  -------------  --------------------------
0 -> 1          [0,2]          1,0.2,3
1 -> 3          [3,6]          4,5,6,5.5
3 -> 5          [7,10]         5.5,8,9,11.1,11
1 -> 5          [3,10]         4,5,6,5.5,8,9,11.1,11
3 -> 10         [7,12]         8,9,11.1,11,12,3 

* Refers to the actual values in ArrayA
```

Note: Given the RangeToExtract `(0->1`), determine the indexes in ArrayA where these values are, the result being `(0->1)` maps to `[0,2]` (The value 1 is in position 2 in ArrayA)

I only figured that the following special cases exists (not sure if there are more)

1. the lower limit is equal to zero and
2. when the upper limit does not exist in ArrayA

Further info:

- Both arrays will be the same size
- ArrayA will always be sorted

Code:

```
private double[] GetRange(double lower, double upper)
{ 
    var myList = new double[ArrayA.Length];
    var lowerIndex = Array.IndexOf(ArrayA, lower);
    var upperIndex = Array.IndexOf(ArrayA, upper);

    // special case 1
    if (lowerIndex != 0)
    {
        lowerIndex = lowerIndex + 1; 
    }

    // special case 2
    if (upperIndex == -1)
    {
        upperIndex = ArrayA.Length-1; 
    }

    for (int i = lowerIndex; i <= upperIndex; i++)
    {
        myList[i] = ArrayB[i];
    }
    return myList;
}
```

Given the above code, have all the special cases been taken into account? Is there a better way to write the above code?

Comment: You should also be sure that values in ArrayA are unique IMO.

Comment: @Marco - the values will always be unique

Comment: Will ArrayA definitely be sorted? Will the values in ArrayB always be 1-N?

Comment: @JonSkeet - ArrayA will always be sorted, and ArrayB will be 1-N

Comment: It looks like you've got an *exclusive* lower bound but an *inclusive* upper bound - is that deliberate? It's somewhat odd - usually it's the other way round. Will the two values you give definitely be in the range in the first place?

Comment: @Ahmad: If ArrayB is always 1-N, then it's irrelevant isn't it? You just need to know the range of indexes, and that tells you everything you need to know. Why bother populating an array or list at all, when the values are just 1-N?

Comment: @JonSkeet -yes, the bounds are deliberate based on business requirements. WRT the bounds provided, there may be a case, as highlighted above where the upper bound does not exist in ArrayA. Re the most recent comment, can you clarify? I need the values to be extracted in different array for further calculations as I don't want to be be reindexing and range finding at every iteration of my calculation.

Comment: @Ahmad: But you wouldn't be reindexing - you're effectively just ending up with a range of values X..Y, right? So why not just remember X and Y? By the way, comparing doubles for equality like this (which is what `IndexOf` does) is usually a bad idea - two values can be very, very close but not actually equal. What are the values here actually meant to represent? (It's possible that `decimal` would be more appropriate than `double`.)

Comment: @Ahmad: Sorry, chat doesn't really work with my workflow.

Comment: @JonSkeet 
Yes I do end up with a range of values from ArrayB. However, I do have multiple ranges that need to be extracted. ArrayA is representing "Years Ahead" in bi-annual steps. ArrayB is the corresponding values at these time intervals. In a seperate method, I generate ArrayA based on some user input, and the specified ranges to bucket will always be integers. I think using double is sufficient.

Comment: @Ahmad: Values of *what* at those time intervals? (Note that the decision about whether or not to use `double` is entirely separate to my objection that it's pointless to create an array of integers 1-N when you just need to remember a lower and upper bound.)

Comment: @JonSkeet - `ArrayA[i]` corresponds to ArrayB[i]`( I don't think I'm following your logic/point.)

Comment: @Ahmad: My point is that if ArrayB will always just be 1, 2, 3, 4... then it's pointless. You're effectively only interested in returning a lower and upper bound. You might want to use a `Tuple<int, int>` for that.

Comment: @JonSkeet - no, I simplified ArrayB with those values for the question. The values in ArrayB will be varied.

Comment: @Ahmad: So when I asked "Will the values in ArrayB always be 1-N?" why did you respond with "ArrayB will be 1-N"? It's very hard to answer a question when we can't get a clear idea of what's going on.

Comment: @JonSkeet - my mistake, I thought you were referring to the size of the array and not the values

Answer (score 0):

Yap! There is a quite better way, that comes with lovely LINQ. I put here in two forms. First looks complicated but not at ALL! Believe me ;)

At the **first** step you have to take out those `A'indexes` that their values fall into your range (I call it `min...max`), based on your example I got that your range is **closed** from the **lower boundary** and **closed** on **upper side**, I means when you mentioned `3 -> 5` actually It is `[3, 5)`! It does not contain 5. Anyway that is not the matter.

This can be done by following LINQ

```
int[] selectedIndexes = a.Select((value, index) => 
   new { Value = value, Index = index }).
      Where(aToken => aToken.Value > min && aToken.Value <= max).
   Select(t => t.Index).ToArray<int>();
```

The **first select**, generates a collection of `[Value, Index]` pairs that the first one is the array element and the second one is the index of the element within the array. I think this is the main trick for your question. So It provides you with this ability to work with the indexes same as usual values.

Finally in the **second Select** I just wrap whole indexes into an integer array. Hence after this you have the whole indexes that their value fall in the given range.

Now **second step**!

When you got those indexes, you have to select whole elements within the **B** under the selected Indexes from the A. The same thing should be done over the B. It means again we select B element into a collection of [Value, Index] pairs and then we select those guys that their indexes exist within the **selected indexes** from the A. This can be done as follow:

```
double[] selectedValues = b.Select((item, index) => 
    new { Item = item, Index = index }).
       Where(bToken => selectedIndexes.Contains(bToken.Index)).
    Select(d => d.Item).ToArray<double>();
```

Ok, so **first select** is the one I talked about it in the fist part and then look at the `where` section that check whether the index of the `bToken` which is an element of B exists in the `selectedIndexes` (from A) or not!

Finally I wrap both codes into one as below:

```
double[] answers = b.Select((item, index) => 
   new { Item = item, Index = index }).
      Where(bTokent =>
         a.Select((value, index) => 
            new { Value = value, Index = index }).
               Where(aToken => aToken.Value > min && aToken.Value <= max).
            Select(t => t.Index).
         Contains(bTokent.Index)).Select(d => d.Item).ToArray<double>();
```

Buy a beer for me, if it would be useful :)

Comment: Your statement about ranges is confused. It's **open** at the bottom and closed at the top, so it's actually `(3, 5]` and *does* contain 5.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still interested, but I saw this one and I liked the challenge. If you use .Net 4 (having the Enumberable.Zip method) there is a very concise way to do this (given the conditions under *futher info*):

```
arrayA.Zip(arrayB, (a,b) => new {a,b})
    .Where(x => x.a > lower && x.a < upper)
    .Select (x => x.b)
```

You may want to use `>=` and `<=` to make the range comparisons inclusive.